# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

So, firstly the layout of the XML file `quran-uthmani.xml` is as follows:

```
<quran>
    <sura index="1" name="الفاتحة">
        <aya index="1" text="بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ" />
        <aya index="2" text="ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَٰلَمِينَ" />
        <aya index="3" text="ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ" />
        <aya index="4" text="مَٰلِكِ يَوْمِ ٱلدِّينِ" />
        <aya index="5" text="إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسْتَعِينُ" />
        <aya index="6" text="ٱهْدِنَا ٱلصِّرَٰطَ ٱلْمُسْتَقِيمَ" />
        <aya index="7" text="صِرَٰطَ ٱلَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ ٱلْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا ٱلضَّآلِّينَ" />
    </sura>
    ...(and basically, this style continues for the rest of the document)
</quran>
```

My aim is to use the `loadDoc()` function to return the data in the xml file, like so:

```
function loadDoc(url) {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        return xhttp.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

and then let the function below access specific nodes using the `s` and `a` parameters:

```
function surah(s, a) {
    s = s - 1;
    xmlDoc = loadDoc("assets/xml/quran-uthmani.xml");
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('sura') + verse(a)[0];
    return x.item(s).children[a].attributes[1].value + verse(a);
}
```

The function is then to be called in a php file to return select nodes from the `quran-uthmani.xml` file and display them on webpage.

This; however, throws the error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined` and I seriously need help figuring this out.

Comment: `loadDoc` is an asynchronous function, that's why there's a callback in it, and returning from the callback returns nothing from the function itself, in fact it will always return `undefined`